# With Styled Components, why does a conditional style not have access to props?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

with Styled Components I have the following:

```
const StyledTextArea = styled.textarea`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.black};

  font-size: 24px;

  ${({ error }) => error && `
    // border-color: red; // for testing to confirm props issue
    border-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.red[1]};
  `}

`;

  <StyledTextArea
    error={error}
  />
```

The textarea color is being set correctly via the theme.

When the prop error is set to true, the commented out border-color works fine, but the dynamic line using props no longer works within the conditional:

```
border-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.red[1]};
```

Why does the conditional not seem to have access to the props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of ways to solve this, the easiest is to put the theme in the original params and use it from there.

```
${({ error, theme }) => error && `
    // border-color: red; // for testing to confirm props issue
    border-color: ${theme.colors.red[1]};
`}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also explicitly set the `border-color` depending on `error`:

```
const StyledTextArea = styled.textarea`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.black};
  font-size: 24px;
  border-color: ${(props) => props.error ? 'red' : 'inherit';
`;
```

Comment: Given an input will also have active hover states this approach could get ugly.